# C++ vector not storing class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am writing a simple feed-forward neural network in c++, however when I try to store my neuron class in my layer structure, it crashes and gives this output:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'`

`what():  std::bad_array_new_length`

`This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.`

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
random_device e;

int randomG(int min, int max){
  return (e()%(max-min))+min;
}

int f(int v){
  return v+5;
}

class neuron{
public:
  neuron(int _insN, int _funtype){
    insN=_insN;funtype=_funtype;
  }
  float out;
  void genWeights(){
    for (int i = 0; i < insN; i++){
      weights[i]=float(randomG(1,1000))/100;
    }
  }
  float parceOut(float* ins){
    float preOut=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < insN; ++i){
      preOut+=(weights[i]*ins[i]);
    }
    out=activation(preOut, funtype);
  }
private:
  float ReLU(float f){
    if (f<=0){return f*0.01;}
    else {return f;}
  }
  float Softmax(float f){
    return f;
  }
  float activation(float f, int function){
    switch(function){
    case(1): return ReLU(f); break;
    case(2): return f; break;
    case(3): return Softmax(f); break;
    }
  }
  int insN;
  int funtype;
  float* weights = new float[insN];
};

struct layer{
  int insN=1, neuronN=1;
  float* outs=new float[neuronN];
  vector<neuron> nS;
  void generateNeurons(){
    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
      nS.push_back(neuron(insN,1));
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  layer input;
  input.insN=1;
  input.neuronN=5;
  input.generateNeurons();
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

I don't think that it is to hard to understand, but if it is I am trying to make a vector with my neuron class in my layer structure, but even when I put just one neuron in the vector it says that there is not enough memory allocated to the program.  I have tried converting the neuron class into a structure, but that did not help.

Comment: Probably initializer for `weights` is being called before `insN` is assigned in the body of the constructor.

Comment: `float* weights = new float[insN];` -- Why are you doing this when you could use `std::vector<float> weights(insN);`?  There is no need for raw pointers in your code -- all dynamic arrays could be done using `vector`.  In addition, your code has memory leaks.

Comment: You don't know what insN is when it's constructed. Add weights = new float[insN]; to the constructor instead of the class body. It's probably being initialized to an array of length 0.

Comment: @ffhighwind  - an array of length zero is permitted  (albeit, any usage of its elements, since it has none, gives undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `weights` member is being inline-initialized using `insN`, before `insN` is initialized. The simplest fix for now would be to change the member declaration to:

```
float* weights;
```

and the constructor to:

```
neuron(int _insN, int _funtype) : insN(_insN), funtype(_funtype), weights(new float[insN]) {

}
```

Note that members in the initialization list are initialized [in the order they are declared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) (see 'Initialization order').

A better long-term solution would be make `weights` be `std::vector<float>`, as well as every other dynamic `float*` array in your code, which currently has a number of memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The `weights` member is being initialised before `insN` is initialised.   Accessing the value of `insN` to do that gives undefined behaviour and an indeterminate amount of memory is being allocated with operator `new`.   That is the reason for the exception which reports a `bad_array_new_length`    (in practice, the number being allocated probably exceeds available memory on your machine although that's just happenstance with your compiler).

That happens before `insN` is being initialised in the constructor.

One partial fix for that will be to remove the initialiser from the class body AND change the constructor to

```
neuron(int _insN, int _funtype) : insN(_insN), funtype(_funtype), weights(new float[_insN])
{}
```

Even if that is fixed, your code has numerous other problems too.  I'll give a partial list here.

`std::vector` assumes its elements have a working copy constructor and assignment operator.   Your class does not, so is not playing by the rules.     That means copying of elements (as, for example, can happen whenever a vector is resized) will create objects that will not behave correctly (e.g. changing an element of `weights` in one object will uninintentionally change an element in another object).   Look up (e.g. using google) the "rule of three" or "rule of five" to address that.    Better yet, make `weights` a `std::vector<float>` rather than a pointer,  and follow the "rule of zero".

Your class doesn't define a destructor, so the memory allocated to `weights` using operator `new` - for each object - is never released.   Hence you have a memory leak - whenever an instance of your `neuron` is created.    Again, look up "rule of three", "rule of five", or "rule of zero" for an approach to address that.

Some of the comments above are applicable to your `layer` class as well.